# Plane Graph and frontiers of faces

Tags: graph-theory

Can someone please give a nice proof to the following statement:

Let $G$ be a plane graph and $e$ an edge of $G$. If $e$ lies on a cycle $C \subseteq  G$, then $e$ lies on the frontier of exactly
two faces of $G$, and these are contained in distinct faces of $C$. If $e$ lies on no cycle, then $e$ lies on the frontier of exactly one face
of $G$.

There is a proof in the book of Reinhard Diestel, Graph Theory, but I don't understand it.

Answer (score 1):

I make this up right now, so this is only supposed to be a possible roadmap.

First we note that an edge cannot be incident to more than two faces.

Assume $e$ lies on a cycle. Then the subgraph containing just this cycle splits the plane into two regions (Jordan curve theorem), one bounded one unbounded, and $e$ is incident to both of these. Note that successively reinserting the old edges lying in the bounded region does not decrease the number of faces $e$ is incident to. Indeed, in the process only the bounded region will be subdivided further, which is strictly separated from the unbounded region, so $e$ is incident to the unbounded face and a face inside the bounded region. Now considering the planar graph embedded on a sphere instead of in the plane, we note that the unbounded face can indeed be viewed as a bounded face (by using another projection from sphere to plane). Hence reinserting edges into the unbounded face does not change anything too.

Assume the edge is not contained in a cycle. Then deleting the edge disconnects the graph (further). By using a similar argument to the previous case we can embed all components of the graph in such a way into the plane, such that the endpoints of $e$ lay on the unbounded face. Hence, reinserting $e$ we find that $e$ is incident to the unbounded face only.

Comment: You are sure this is correct?

Comment: Kind of, but as I said I made this up on the go... Is there anything, which worries you with this?

Comment: I don't understand why you are considering the graph on a sphere?

Comment: I should have written this in a better way. What I wanted to state is that, given a planar embedding of a graph, any face can be turned into the unbounded face. This is usually done by identifying the plane with the punctured sphere (look up stereographic projection) and then moving the puncture onto the face, which shall turn into the unbounded face. In my argument above I needed this for arguing that the distinction between unbounded and bounded is unnecessary and for the fact that *e* can be made to connect different components through the unbounded face

Comment: you can also turn any bounded face into an unbounded?

Comment: While the unbounded turns into a bounded one, yes. Imagine drawing your graph onto a sphere (which you can certainly do, as a sphere is a 2-dimensional manifold (locally looks like a plane), and then puncture a hole into any face and stretch the sphere out. This will make this face an unbounded face...

Comment: I will continue to think. Many thanks for your effort :)

Comment: No problem! Good luck :)